# Method to Solve Exponential Diophantine equations of the type:$ \frac{1}{3} 2^l \left(\frac{1}{3} 2^{2 m-1} \left(2^{2 (3 n-1)}-1\right)-1\right)$

Tags: diophantine-equations, exponential-diophantine-equations

Im in need to solve a large set of Exponential Diophantine Equations of the type
$$\frac{1}{3} \left(\frac{1}{3} \left(-1+2^{2 (3 n-1)}\right) 2^{2 m-1}-1\right) 2^l\equiv 0\pmod3.$$

By inspection I arrive at the following solutions:

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{3} \left(\frac{1}{3} \left(-1+2^{2 (3 (3 n-2)-1)}\right) 2^{2 (3 m-1)-1}-1\right) 2^{2 l}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{3} \left(\frac{1}{3} \left(-1+2^{2 (3 (3 n-1)-1)}\right) 2^{2 (3 m)-1}-1\right) 2^{2 l}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{3} \left(\frac{1}{3} \left(-1+2^{2 (3 (3 n)-1)}\right) 2^{2 (3 m-2)-1}-1\right) 2^{2 l} 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{3} \left(\frac{1}{3} \left(-1+2^{2 (3 (3 n-2)-1)}\right) 2^{2 (3 m)-1}-1\right) 2^{2 l-1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{3} \left(\frac{1}{3} \left(-1+2^{2 (3 (3 n-1)-1)}\right) 2^{2 (3 m-2)-1}-1\right) 2^{2 l-1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{3} \left(\frac{1}{3} \left(-1+2^{2 (3 (3 n)-1)}\right) 2^{2 (3 m-1)-1}-1\right) 2^{2 l-1}
\end{equation}

As the equations get longer, solving by inspection become too cumbersome, can anyone point me in a direction to systematically solve this kind of equation?

Tank you

Comment: I don't see what you mean by those being solutions. Solutions are of the form $m=\dots, n=\dots, l=\dots.$

Comment: Oh, sure, I just substituted the variables on the previous equation. Iam trying to find the subset of {$\frac{1}{3} \left(\frac{1}{3} \left(-1+2^{2 (3 n-1)}\right) 2^{2 m-1}-1\right) 2^l$} tha is divisible by 3

Comment: Clearly, $l\geq0$ can be any integer. Then you want $$(2^{6n-2}-1)2^{2m-1}\equiv 3\pmod {27}$$ So you want $$2^{6n-2}-1\equiv 3(14)^{2m-1}\pmod 3.$$ Then this just amounts to listing the values of$2^{6n-2}-1$ and $3(14)^{2m-1},$ and finding the values in the first that are one more than a value in the second.

Comment: But by writing that, you solution is, say, $l:=2l,$ which is very confusing. You are abusing notation and confusing readers by using $n,m,l$ to mean something else in your "answers." And it makes your "answers" harder to read - you can't see any patterns.

Comment: You are right, I see that it is not clear, I am sorry

Comment: So, $3(14)^{2n-1}\equiv 6\cdot 7^n\pmod {27}$ and it can take values $6, 15, 24.$ Similarly, $2^{6n-2}\equiv 7\cdot 10^n\pmod {27},$ and $10$ has period $3$ modulo $27,$ so it takes only three values, $7, 16, 25.$ From this, we see that $n\equiv m\pmod 3$ and $l$ can be any positive integer.